# @Config constants parameter could not be found in Robolectric

Tags: android, android-testing, robolectric, android-junit

I am trying to write a **Robolectric** test. I was following few tutorials where they seem to be using

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig::class)
```

to setup the test, but in my case The parameter constants does not seem to resolve.

[image]

My Robolectric dependency looks like this:

```
testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:4.0.2"
```

Comment: have you resolved your issue? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: Not yet, I haven't been looking into it lately

Answer (score 19):

`constants` parameter is now deprecated see the [doc](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/3.5/org/robolectric/annotation/Config.html) :

```
constants
Deprecated. 
If you are using at least Android Studio 3.0 alpha 5 please migrate to the 
preferred way to configure builds for Gradle with AGP3.0 
http://robolectric.org/getting-started/
```

The proper way to set up Robolectric per the [documentation](http://robolectric.org/getting-started/) is :

```
android {
  testOptions {
    unitTests {
      includeAndroidResources = true
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Robolectric is for `unit` test, not for `androidTest`, so please confirm that your test case is under `src/test`, NOT under `src/androidTest`.

Comment: Yes is inside src/test  its my reference Project/app/src/test/java/com/erluxman/productive/MainActivityRoboTest.kt